# Only apply classes on small screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I am on a desktop mode I need the navbar to be without any background color.
The code for my navbar on desktop mode is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
```

But when I go on the small screen devices I need two other classes to be applied to my navbar:

this `navbar-light` and  this `bg-light`.

How do I do this, using media-queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add the classes to the div but have the styling for the classes in the media queries.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
        .navbar-light{/*your style*/}
        .bg-light{/*your style*/}
    }
```

Comment: What do I write at the styles of .navbar-light and .bg-light so they can only be applied when the max-width: 480px

Comment: @IbrahimKunushefci the media query that I have provided will create those classes at 480px width and lower. However, I can't answer what style you should put in the area that I designated `your style` as you will need to put the styles in there to make the required changes.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of media queries your problem can be solved;

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

    @media only screen
       and (min-device-width: 320px) 
       and (max-device-width : 480px)
        {
        .navbar-light
               {/*styling*/}
        .bg-light
               {/*styling*/}
        }
```