# bootstrap - apply class based on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can I do this without using @media only screen ? Or is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834828/only-apply-classes-on-small-screen-sizes) the best way?

For example can I write this in CSS?:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  .card {
    transform: translate(0px, -75px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}
```

I also want to hide/show a div based on screen size.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to change? Bootstrap includes responsive classes for some common styling changes, but this would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use a media query for the transform, but you can use the built-in Bootstrap breakpoints for the display property. E.g. `d-md-none` will hide the element on `md` size and up.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create multiple css style sheets based on your media screen sizes. then inside one of your css style sheets for that particular screen size you can hide your div.

Example link in your html:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1920px)" href= "styles/desktop.css"/>
```

then inside desktop.css you can have:

```
.card { display = none; }
```

This will hide your div when the screen size is between 480px and 1920px.

Answer (score 3):

For showing/hiding divs based on screen size, bootstrap has a few classes made to fit the standard bootstrap breakpoints to show/hide depending on screen size:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/